# How can I embed an image sequence so I can export a .gltf, .fbx, .obj file etc. that retains that animation?

Tags: export, image, texture-baking, gltf, image-sequence

I have a simple rectangular plane that has a 2D png image sequence applied to it. Super simple, I built it using the Import > Images as Planes method. It seems to working well in blender, because I can see my animation playing correctly in the render and material views. However, when I export it there doesn't seem to be a setting I can activate to embed that image sequence onto my object. I'm trying to use my animation in Reality Composer so I need it in some kind of 3d file format type. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know. I've tried to bake the image sequence but that doesn't seem to do anything (maybe I'm not doing it correctly?). Any help is super appreciated, thank you!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Video textures aren't currently supported in glTF. It's possible one could embed a very short sequence of images by placing each image on its own "Plane" mesh, and animating them such that only one is visible at a time (for example, set scale to zero, animate scale to STEP to 1 at that particular image's animation time, and then STEP back to scale zero when the next image's animation time is reached).  But this wouldn't work well with enough images for smooth video, I don't think.